# Unable to execute spark job using SparkSubmitOperator

Tags: airflow

I am able to run `Spark` job using `BashOperator` but I want to use `SparkSubmitOperator` for it using `Spark` **standalone mode**.

---

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/mandar2174/c3f101d7d8c17bd28ff5134d3afdf025) my `DAG` for `SparkSubmitOperator` and *stack-trace*

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 24)
}
dag = DAG('spark_job', default_args=args, schedule_interval="*/10 * * * *")

operator = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_job',
    application='/home/ubuntu/test.py',
    total_executor_cores='1',
    executor_cores='1',
    executor_memory='2g',
    num_executors='1',
    name='airflow-spark',
    verbose=False,
    driver_memory='1g',
    conf={'master':'spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:7077'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

---

Looking at source for [`spark_submit_hook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py) it seems `_resolve_connection()` always sets `master=yarn`. How can I change `master` *properties value* by `Spark` standalone master URL? Which properties I can set to run `Spark` job in *standalone mode*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can either create a new connection using the Airflow Web UI or change the `spark-default` connection.

[image: Change Spark-default connection in Airflo]

Master can be `local`, `yarn`, `spark://HOST:PORT`, `mesos://HOST:PORT` and `k8s://https://<HOST>:<PORT>`.

You can also supply the following commands in the extras:

```
{"queue": "root.default", "deploy_mode": "cluster", "spark_home": "", "spark_binary": "spark-submit", "namespace": "default"}
```

[image: Airflow Spark Submit Extras]

Either the "spark-submit" binary should be in the PATH or the spark-home is set in the extra on the connection.

Comment: above solution works perfectly by changing connection details for spark-default. Thanks

Comment: I am running two container, one of them is for spark and other is airflow. How can I set spark-submit binary?

Comment: Be careful with `{"queue": "root.default", "deploy_mode": "cluster", "spark_home": "", "spark_binary": "spark-submit", "namespace": "default"}`, it should be `deploy-mode` instead of `deploy_mode`, Using spark 2.4.2 the former didn't work, it's not straightforward to debug :)

Comment: `{"queue": "default", "deploy-mode": "cluster", "spark-home": "", "spark-binary": "spark-submit", "namespace": "default"}`
from https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/connection/spark.html